# Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException Image source not readable

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to resize images using the intervention package, but I keep on getting the error, whenever I refresh the browser page. I have already added Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class, to the providers section and, 'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class, to the aliases section of config/app.php file.

```
if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $imagePath = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $imagePath->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
            $imagePath->storeAs('public/uploads/', $filename);
            
        }

        $image = Image::make(public_path("public/uploads/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200,1200);
        $image->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add "public" with the `public_path()` function (unless you actually have a "public" folder inside Laravel's public folder.

So your file path should probably be:

```
public_path("uploads/{$imagePath}")
```

If it still doesn't work, echo out the path to check if it's correct.